Extra space within framed tikzpicture
I don't know why there is that extra space inside the frame, to the right of the graph. What am I doing wrong?

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

\settrimmedsize{11in}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{7.75in}{33pc}{*}
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{1in}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,framed]%[xscale = 2]                                                                                                         
  \draw[-latex, name path = xline] (.4, 0) -- (4.25, 0) node[right, font = \small]
  {x};
  \draw[-latex] (0.5, -.2) -- (0.5, 1.6) node[right, font = \small] {y};
  \draw[blue!40, name path = para] plot[domain = 1.1:4.1, samples = 100]
({\x}, {sqrt((\x-1)/2)});
   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \foreach \yl/\i in {0.774596/1}{
      \path[name path global = \i] (0.5, \yl) -- +(5, 0);
      \path[name intersections = {of = para and \i, by = P\i}];
      \draw[dashed] (0.5, \yl) -- (P\i);
      \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \path[name path global = Pxl\i] (P\i) -- +(0, -2);
      \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
      \path[name intersections = {of = xline and Pxl\i, by = Xl\i}];
      \draw[dashed] (P\i) -- (Xl\i);
    }
    \foreach \y/\i in {0.83/3, 0.9/4, 1/5, 1.1/6}{
      \path[name path global = \i] (0.5, \y) -- +(5, 0);
      \path[name intersections = {of = para and \i, by = Q\i}];
      \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \path[name path global = Qx\i] (Q\i) -- +(0, -2);
      \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
      \path[name intersections = {of = xline and Qx\i, by = X\i}];
    }
    \foreach \yu/\i in {1.183216/2}{
      \path[name path global = \i] (0.5, \yu) -- +(5, 0);
      \path[name intersections = {of = para and \i, by = R\i}];
      \draw[dashed] (0.5, \yu) -- (R\i);
      \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \path[name path global = Rxu\i] (R\i) -- +(0, -2);
      \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
      \path[name intersections = {of = xline and Rxu\i, by = Xu\i}];
      \draw[dashed] (R\i) -- (Xu\i);
    }
  \end{scope}
  \fill[green!20] (0.5,0.774596)--(P1)--(Xl1)--(Xu2)--(R2)--(0.5,1.183216)--cycle;
  \draw[loosely dotted] (0.5, 0.83) -- (Q3) -- (X3);
  \draw[loosely dashed] (0.5, 0.9) -- (Q4) -- (X4);
  \draw[loosely dotted] (0.5, 1) -- (Q5) -- (X5);
  \draw[loosely dashed] (0.5, 1.1) -- (Q6) -- (X6);
  \draw (2.2, .05) -- (2.2, -.05) node[below, font = \footnotesize,xshift=-4pt] {$a-\delta_1$};
  \draw (2.3778, .05) -- (2.3778, -.05) node[below, font = \footnotesize,yshift=-2pt] {$x$};
  \draw (2.62, .05) -- (2.62, -.05) node[below, font = \footnotesize, xshift=2pt] {$a-\delta_2$};
  \draw (3, .05) -- (3, -.05) node[below, font = \footnotesize, yshift=-2pt] {$a$};
  \draw (3.42, .05) -- (3.42, -.05) node[below, font = \footnotesize] {$a+\delta_2$};
  \draw (3.8, .05) -- (3.8, -.05) node[below, font = \footnotesize, xshift=2pt] {$a+\delta_1$};
  \draw (.55,{sqrt(0.4)}) -- (.45,{sqrt(0.4)}) node[left,font =\footnotesize] {$L-\eps_1$};
  \draw (.55,{sqrt(0.6889)}) -- (.45,{sqrt(0.6889)}) node[left,font =\footnotesize] {$f(x)$};
  \draw (.55,{sqrt{0.81}}) -- (.45,{sqrt(.81)});
  \draw[dashed] (.45,{sqrt(.81)}) -- (.1,{sqrt(.81)}) node[left,font=\footnotesize] {$L-\eps_2$};
  \draw (.55,{sqrt(1)}) -- (.45,{sqrt(1)}) node[left,font =\footnotesize] {$L$};
  \draw (.55,{sqrt{1.21}}) -- (.45,{sqrt(1.21)});
  \draw[dashed] (.45,{sqrt(1.21)}) -- (.1,{sqrt(1.21)}) node[left,font=\footnotesize] {$L+\eps_2$};
  \draw (.55,{sqrt(1.75)}) -- (.45,{sqrt(1.75)}) node[left,font =\footnotesize] {$L+\eps_1$};
 \draw[blue!40, name path = para] plot[domain = 1.1:4.1, samples = 100]
 ({\x}, {sqrt((\x-1)/2)});
 \draw[blue!40, fill = white] (3, 1) circle[radius = .025cm];
 \draw[blue!40, fill = blue!40] (Q3) circle[radius = .025cm];
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Reducción del valor $\eps$}\label{reps}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}


Do you need to interrupt the picture for the remaining global paths?

Do you mean that I use the \foreach command more than once?

No. That perhaps some of your other \paths which don't draw anything also need to not affect the bounding box. I didn't look into this, so perhaps you have good reason for letting them contribute to the bounding box.

I applied pascal974's solution but the frame still invades the right margin. I've been checking to see if something else causes this but I can't find anything.

I found what caused that small invasion to the right margin, it was an additional change, to pascal974's solution, that I made.

Oh, OK. I was going to look, but I've only got as far as compiling your code.

Could I ask you a favor?

You can always ask. I don't guarantee any particular answer. ;)

I asked a question a few days ago about getting all the symbols in the MnSymbol package colored “by default” (I don't know if I'm explaining myself well). Is it possible that you can give me some suggestions with this?

I can take a look, though probably not right now. It doesn't sound like something I'm likely to be able answer if nobody else has, but maybe I can help with the question.

Do I need to send you the link to my question?

No, but I'm not hunting down Manrope to test it ;). See comment there.

In your 3 foreach you have  +(5,0)
\path[name path global = \i] (0.5, \yl) -- +(5, 0); 

\path[name path global = \i] (0.5, \y) -- +(5, 0);

\path[name path global = \i] (0.5, \yu) -- +(5, 0);

And x axis is set up to 4.25
\draw[-latex, name path = xline] (.4, 0) -- (4.25, 0) node[right, font = \small]
{x};
you can replace with \path[name path global = \i] (0.5, \yl) -- (4.25, 0);
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,framed]

    \draw[-latex, name path = xline] (.4, 0) -- (4.25, 0) node[right, font = \small]
    {x};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \foreach \yl/\i in {0.774596/1}{
                % \path[name path global = \i] (0.5, \yl) -- +(5, 0);
                \path[name path global = \i] (0.5, \yl) -- (4.25, 0);
            }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thanks. This works perfectly.
